# Impossible to import a package I made. "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a project organized like so :

```
application
 ├── app
 │   └── package
         └── __init__.py
 │       └── functions.py
 └── app2
     └── some_folder
         └── file_2.py
```

My "functions.py" contains a basic function:

```
#functions.py
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

The file "**_*init*_.py" is empty**

I want to use the "add" function in my "file_2.py" file, so I write:

```
#file_2.py
from application.app.package.functions import add
print(add(2,3))
```

But it returns an error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'

it is the same if i try any of these:

```
from app.package.functions import add
from package.functions import add
from functions import add
```

Does anyone know where the problem comes from? I'm doing exactly like in this tutorial so I don't understand what's wrong

[tutorial's link](https://blog.finxter.com/python-how-to-import-modules-from-another-folder/)

Thank you for your help

Comment: your `folder1` is called app, right?

Comment: sorry, yes indeed, I'll correct that in the post

Answer (score 1):

One way to import functions.add is to import sys and use sys.path.insert()
after that you can import add from functions:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, 'the/local/path/to/package')

from functions import add

print(add(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks it indeed work!  But wasn't the point of creating a package to not have to do this ?